# Create filter that contains the functionality of `raw` in TWIG

Tags: twig, twig-extension

I am trying to create custom twig filter that contains the functionality of built-in raw filter. 
This is the way I am trying to achieve that currently.

```
$twig->addFilter(new Twig_Filter('wp_raw', function($content) {
  return apply_filters('the_content', $content);
}, ['is_safe' => ['html']]));
```

But output of my filter still comes out surrounded by quotes rather than a raw output such as when I apply `raw` filter to any string variable.

Is there an easy way of achieving this, as otherwise I need to first apply the my custom filter than chain raw filter in order to achieve this like so. `{{ post_content | wp_raw | raw }}`.

Comment: Having the `is_safe` option should suffice, what kind of content are you returning? In the worst case u'd could do `return new \Twig_Markup(apply_filters('the_content', $content), 'UTF-8');`

Comment: its html string. But for some reason it is surrounded by " "

Comment: Should work then